# Stop Session Expiring on App Restart

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

We constantly deploy updates to our application

However each deploy terminates all user sessions.

I want to implement a session system that doesnt have this issue using cookies or similar.

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically four ways of handling session (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx)):

> **InProc mode**, which stores session state in memory on the Web server. This is the default.
>   **StateServer mode**, which stores session state in a separate process called the ASP.NET state service. This ensures that session state is
>   preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session
>   state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.
>
> **SQLServer mode** stores session state in a SQL Server database. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is
>   restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web
>   servers in a Web farm.
>
> **Custom mode**, which enables you to specify a custom storage provider.

You are, most likely, using **In Process** session (the first one listed) which is causing the session drops during the deployment process.

Moving to any of the others would meet your requirement, but none are instance and they all have upsides and downsides, so you'd need to pick the one that meets your (and your organizations) needs.